# How to import scss file in compass only if it exists?

Tags: compass-sass, sass

I need to have special scss file that is different for every installation of the project, so I don't want to include it in git archive. But everything should work even if this file doesn't exist.

Is there any way to @import scss file only if it exists, ignoring file not found error?

Comment: What's wrong with just including a blank file?

Comment: I need to put it under source control so these project dependant scss modules should be gitignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to make use of the "import-path" option to do this, where the path you're importing contains the fallback files you want to import (in our case, we want an empty file).

## Option 1: Vanilla Sass

**File structure**

```
├── fallback
    ├── _example.scss // <-- our blank file
├── _example.scss // <-- the file for the user to customize (optional)
├── style.scss
```

**In style.scss:**

```css
@import "example";
/* the rest of our styles */
```

When you run your sass command, you would write it like this:

```
sass --watch ./css:./sass --load-path ./sass/fallback
```

Note that the fallback directory does not have to be inside your sass directory, it be anywhere on the filesystem you like.

See also: [How does SCSS locate partials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27282608/how-does-scss-locate-partials)

## Option 2: Compass Extension

You may find that creating a Compass extension is a little more convenient if you're using this technique in multiple projects.  It will automatically setup the load-path for you.  You can learn more about creating extensions here: http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/extensions/

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need. I actually went a bit different way, and set `additional_import_paths = ["./lib"]` where I placed modules that may be overridden so it looks for local files and then inside "./lib"

Answer (score 2):

Maybe with [sass-globbing](http://rubygems.org/gems/sass-globbing) and a naming convention for optional files follow a specific order of loading.

Consider the following tree:

```
stackoverflow-14975341/
├── .gitignore
├── config.rb
├── css/
│   └── screen.css
└── sass/
    ├── optionals/
    │   ├── .gitkeep
    │   ├── _01_style.scss
    │   └── _03_style.scss
    └── screen.scss
```

with these files:

```
# config.rb
require 'sass-globbing'

sass_dir   = 'sass'
css_dir    = 'css'
relative_assets = true
```

and

```
// sass/screen.scss
@import "optionals/*";
```

and

```
// sass/optionals/_01_style.scss
.optional1 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

and

```
// sass/optionals/_03_style.scss
.optional3 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

and, for in the `.gitignore`:

```
sass/optional/*
```

Finally, to keep the `optional` folder, create an empty file named `.gitkeep` (the file name is not important).

When you compile the stylesheet, Compass generates the `screen.css` even if the file `_02_style.scss` is missing.

```
// css/screen.css
/* line 1, ../sass/optionals/_01_style.scss */
.optional1 {
  background-color: red;
}

/* line 1, ../sass/optionals/_03_style.scss */
.optional3 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

It is certainly possible to improve the system based on import additional paths.

Comment: So I guess it is not possible out of box without additional plugins? I was thinking about possibility to override specific scss module by having two paths for scss module lookup. So if override module isn't found, then the default one is imported. Is it possible?