# How does SCSS locate partials?

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

I'm looking through the [bower foundation project](https://github.com/zurb/bower-foundation) and I'm getting stumped on how the project is able to locate the partials. In particular, I'm looking at the `_settings.scss` [that has a relative reference in it](https://github.com/zurb/bower-foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/_settings.scss#L58) I just don't quite understand.

On line 58 there is a reference to `foundation/functions` but this partial (`_functions.scss`) is a sibling of the settings partial. I'm confused as why there is a reference to the parent directory `foundation` on that line. I'm also confused as to how this works. Why would the settings file not look for a directory named foundation at the same level?

Answer (score 1):

The answer becomes clear if you attempt to import a file that does not exist.  Here's an excerpt of the error generated on http://sassmeister.com/ when you try to `import "foo";` (which doesn't exist):

```
File to import not found or unreadable: foo.
Load paths:
  /app
  /app/lib/sass_modules
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.6/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.6/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/susy-1.0.9/sass
```

If Sass begins searching for the requested file relative to each of those directories until it finds it.

For vanilla Sass, one would add extra paths via the `--import-path` option:

```
sass --watch test.scss:test.css --load-path ../path/to/lib/ --load-path ../path/to/otherlib/
```

Compass users would use `additional_import_paths` or `add_import_path` in their config.rb (see: http://compass-style.org/help/documentation/configuration-reference/)

```
add_import_path "../path/to/lib/"
```

Only the authors of Foundation can answer your specific question as to *why* they would write the import that way.  But this is why it works.

Answer (score 0):

Look at line 2 of your config.rb

```
add_import_path "bower_components/foundation/scss"
```

If you look at the sass in the file, the bower_components/foundation/_foundation.scss is just full of blanket imports for the rest of the components in foundation/components