# Change CSS compile folder in compass for extensions

Tags: css, sass, compass

in my project I have multiple sites that share common SASS files. Some of them implement their own, custom rules (in _custom.scss); others don't. So for some of the sites there is no _custom.scss file (but it is imported in common SASS anyway). To avoid putting empty _custom.scss files in each local SASS folder I created an extension in compass (like it was suggested here [How to import scss file in compass only if it exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975341/how-to-import-scss-file-in-compass-only-if-it-exists)).

But there is problem: the compiled CSS goes into css/extension_name/stylesheets folder. I want it to go into css/ folder.

I have my css_dir set to "css" but still the compiled CSS goes into css/extension_name/stylesheets. I could move the file each time but I don't think it's a good practice.

Can somebody suggest some solutions? Any help would be appreciated.