# Validate and import files in sass?

Tags: css, sass

Is it possible to check the import path in sass/scss?

For example:

```
@if(path('../../path_to_import') != undefined)
     @import '../../path_to_import';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975341/how-to-import-scss-file-in-compass-only-if-it-exists