# How can i use global scss variables overwrite my node modules

Tags: npm, webpack, sass

I created a personal UI-framework (react-components),and want to share the framework with some of my projects.

For good management, I want to upload my framework on NPM.

I used SCSS for my framework consisting of one global SCSS variables file.
How would I approach this if I want to use a different global variable value for each project? I want to set my global variable file out of the node-modules folder.

Would this affect global variables into the node-module from out of the node-modules folder?

Any solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will this reference help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975341/how-to-import-scss-file-in-compass-only-if-it-exists ... You can have an optional sass variable file import, located outside your project folder and outside your node module. If the file with variables exist in your project, styles would change else the default styles will be generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SCSS allows you to define default values for variables, which can be overruled.

Example file in your project `app.scss`

```
$some_color: blue;
@import 'node_modules/yourframework/main'; // This is your frameworks main file
```

Example file in your framework `node_modules/yourframework/main.scss`

```
$some_color: red !default;
body{
   background-color: $some_color;
}
```

This will result in your body's background being blue.

Good luck!

Comment: Can i ask you one more Q ?,  how does it work?  coz node_modules/my-framework/main is built file so there is no scss. it is css. How they know there is scss variable ?